# Synchronize result with value changed in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I wrote .vue file like below to change `h1#msg` after 100ms.

```
<template>
  <div id="main">
    <h1 id="msg">{{ msg }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Top',
  data () {
    let a=['TEST']
    setTimeout((function(a){a[0]='test'}),100)
    return {
      msg: a
    }
  }
}
</script>
<style>
</style>
```

However I cannot change state by this code. I tried to use Array to pass value by reference.
I don't like to use querySelector(), because it forces me to add attitude in HTML and arguments for methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code snippets

```
<template>
  <div id="main">
    <h1 id="msg">{{ msg }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
  name: 'Top',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'a'
    }
  },
  created() {
    setTimeout(() => this.msg = 'Hello World!', 100)
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Dont write javascript inside `data()`, the correct is this code:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'top',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'test'
    }
  }
  mounted() {
    setTimeout(() => this.msg = 'Bu!', 100)
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `data` should just declare the variable to whatever you want it to be before the change. Then do the `timeout` in `mounted`.